# No External Content on some Websites

Tags: firefox, noscript

Right now, my browser, Firefox v47, doesn't seem to load CSS Files on some Websites, especially on Secured Websites ([https](/questions/tagged/https)).

I have tried restarting on Safe Mode (on Firefox), in which, it will restart with add - ons disabled; but, this doesn't work *(for me)*

I have add - ons installed on Firefox, which blocks pages from accessing external content, such as [`No-Script Suite Lite`](http://mybrowseraddon.com/noscript-lite.html) and [`NoScript`](https://noscript.net); but I whitelisted some of the pages that's causing error.  Nothing works ...

Some pages that can't load their external content are:

- Github
- CSS Tricks
- Codepen
- as well as, Mozilla Support (`https://support.mozilla.org/en-US`)

  ... and other sites, but not Google, JSFiddle, and other sites that use HTTPS.

Other sites only display Firefox's error page:

(`about:neterror?e=nssFailure2&u=http://example.com&c=UTF-8&f=regular&d=An%20error%20occured%20during%20a%20connection%20to%20http://example.com%0A%0AThe%20OCSP%20response%20is%20not%20yet%20valid%20(contains%20a%20date%20in%20the%20future).%0A%0AError%20code%3A%20<a%20id%3D"errorCode"%20title%3D"SEC_ERROR_OCSP_FUTURE_RESPONSE">SEC_ERROR_OCSP_FUTURE_RESPONSE</a>%0A`) -- the Error Page ...

Comment: Is this at home or at work...

Comment: And what if you use another browser?

Comment: This is my Home Computer.  Other browsers work fine, such as in Chrome (I don't like to use IE).  Maybe the issue is in the `about:config` ...

Comment: Hi!  If you ("someone") would mind editing my question, I can't attach links more than 2 ... Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The OCSP response is not yet valid (contains a date in the future).
>
> Error code: SEC_ERROR_OCSP_FUTURE_RESPONSE

Sounds like your computer's clock or time zone is not set correctly.

By the way: it seems the error code is clickable, so probably gives you more details?

Comment: Oh, yes! Maybe that could solve the problem.  I'll try to sync my Computer Time with an Internet Time.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the solution!  Firefox is now working correctly.  I don't know why my Computer Time is changing anytime.

Comment: I now know why my Computer Time's changing, it's that battery from the CPU; it's somewhat "expired" or low battery, so the Computer Time will start over again.

Comment: @LloydDominic, I've no idea what important other things [your CMOS/clock battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonvolatile_BIOS_memory#CMOS_battery) might be needed for, but if your only problem is the time, then syncing with Internet Time (NTP) like you commented should fix that? By the time you open a browser after booting, the OS could have updated its time. And I don't think the battery is used while powered up. (As an aside: cheap computers, like a Raspberry Pi, don't have any CMOS battery and fully rely on NTP.)